# Fetching AWS Cloudfront performance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an AWS s3 bucket and cloudfront url. I want to prevent open the url from the tab but I want to open it in my app.
First question is, can I add a required header to request headers for cloudfront url? For now, I am getting the data like below:

```
fetch(url, {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
       }
   }).then(res => res.blob())
       .then(blob => {
           const urlObject = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           document.querySelector('#output-frame-id').setAttribute("src", urlObject);
      })
```

The second one is, this is a video url and I have to wait until all the content is downloaded. Is there any better way to get data with request header without waiting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Signed CloudFront Urls. Setup the key in your AWS account (this can *only* be done by the root user) and sign your requests to CloudFront with it. A common way is to use the Cookie auth method where CF creates the signed cookie for you and you add it to all requests from your app. You just have to initially identify your app somehow.

Comment: But still, if I can see the url in an iframe etc., I can open it in a  browser tab. how to solve this problem?